# Array data not producing correct calculations into output

Tags: c++, arrays, terminal, assignment-operator

So I have a Weight Calculator assignment that I am doing for Uni and my Teachers cannot solve my issue. I have spent about three days trying to figure this out. I have executed the code by hand also and traced the steps and cannot figure it out.

I receive no errors but the calculations do not produce logical outcomes.

Oddly it is a very small program and produces the same result on multiple devices so it isn't just my PC or Tablet. I think the issue might be in the storing of the weight data in the first place, rather than the calculation itself.

I will try not to put too much code in but at the same time I want you guys to understand how I have built the program. I believe that nothing is being stored correctly into result.weight

I am fairly new to C++ and I have transitioned to Pascal. If there is something wrong with my logic in the code please help me out as it should work in my eyes.

```
part_data read_part()
{
    int option;
    part_data result;
    result.name = read_string("Please Enter a name: ");
    result.kind = read_part_kind();
    result.weight = read_float("Please Enter weight: ");
}

float weight_of_kind(part_array &data, partkind kind)
{
    int i = 0;
    float result = 0.0;

    for (i = 0; i< data.num; i++);
    {
        if (data.array[i].kind == kind)
        {
            result += data.array[i].weight;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

float total_weight(part_array &data)
{
    float result = 0.0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.num; i++)
    {
        result += data.array[i].weight;
    }
    return result;
}

void calculate_weight(part_array &data)
{
    int i;
    printf("Total weight: %4.2f\n", total_weight(data));
    printf("Total CRITICAL: %4.2f\n", weight_of_kind(data, CRITICAL));
    printf("Total DESIRED: %4.2f\n", weight_of_kind(data, DESIRED));
    printf("Total OPTIONAL: %4.2f\n", weight_of_kind(data, OPTIONAL));
}
```

Also, here are the types for reference

```
enum partkind {
    CRITICAL, DESIRED, OPTIONAL
};

typedef struct
{
    my_string name;//array
    partkind kind;
    long weight;
} part_data;

typedef struct 
{
    part_data *array; // pointer to a part
    int num;          // number of parts
} part_array;
```

This is the output I get when I try to produce a calculation of multiple persons' weights, categorized by kind (Critical, Desired or Optional)

[image]

---

UPDATE: 
Here are other related functions that are in the program that might help us debug. I appreciate all of the help I am getting and that you guys have refrained from 'downvoting' I know how tempting it is for some people

```
partkind read_part_kind()
{
        printf("1 - Critical\n");
        printf("2 - Desired\n");
        printf("3 - Optional\n");
    switch( read_integer_range("Please select a part kind: ", 1, 3) )
    {
        case 1: return CRITICAL;
        case 2: return DESIRED;
        default: return OPTIONAL;
    }
}

part_data read_part()
{
    int option;
    part_data result;

    result.name = read_string("Please Enter a name: ");
    result.kind = read_part_kind();
    result.weight = read_float("Please Enter weight: ");

    return result;
}

void add_part(part_array &data)
{
    data.num++;
    data.array = (part_data*) realloc(data.array, sizeof(part_data)*data.num);
    data.array[data.num - 1] = read_part();
}
```

I hope this code helps make a little more sense out of why the input isn't getting assigned correctly and why Total weight is producing (seemingly) random memory.

Comment: Where and how you are allocating `data.array`??

Comment: data is initialized in Main() as a part_array type

Comment: IMHO you would be better off to have `std::vector<part_data> array;` instead of `part_data *array;`! This will alleviate solving you from all these memory management problems. Or did you actually ask for plain [tag:c] code? Then retag your question appropriately please.

Comment: Well, here's another thing. You are passing this variable called 'data' as an argument to all the functions, but you didn't post the code, in which you are declaring and initializing it. I'd bet that this might be another source of errors, especially that for some reason you are using references.

Comment: It might not be the answer you expect, but read some C++ book, because your current code shows that you have a very vague idea of what you are doing. We may help you solve this one problem now, and I'm sure you are going to run at another problem like that immediately after that.

Your function add_part() shows that your biggest problem would be solved by using std::vector, as @πάνταῥεῖ suggested. It will enable you to do all the things you're trying to do now much simpler. Also redesigning the code and e.g. adding some constructors initializing variables would make it less bug-prone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use a pointer **part_data* array** in functions **calculate_weight()** and **total_weight()** without initializing it, which causes it to contain random garbage. Before you can use that array, you should allocate a memory for it like this:

```
array = new part_data[n]
```

where **n** is the number of elements in the array. In your case you probably want **n** to equal **data.num**.

Also, you declare that **readPart()** function would return **part_data**, but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I have iinitialized it as  

data.array = NULL;

Is that now how I should have done so? Note my types

Comment: NULL doesn't initialize. It means that no memory is reserved for your variable. You should initialize it with a "new".

Comment: Just like @Kabulan0lak said.

Answer (score 2):

Your `readPart()` function doesn't return anything but it should return a `part_data`. And try to change the variable `weight` in `float` not `long` because your calculus returns a `float`.

```
typedef struct {
    my_string name;//array
    partkind kind;
    float weight; // <<<<<<<
} part_data;
```

AND return a part_data in `read_part()`  :

```
part_data read_part()
{
    int option;
    part_data result;
    result.name = read_string("Please Enter a name: ");
    result.kind = read_part_kind();
    result.weight = read_float("Please Enter weight: ");
    return result; // <<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that oversight. That has made my total weight now produce extraordinary numbers in POSITIVE. Well that's a plus I guess! 

Meanwhile that was not what was causing my problem there is still something wrong. Can I post more code here?

Comment: It would be good to see how you use the `read_part()` function.

Comment: I call read_part() from my add_part function. Funny you mention that as this is where I initially thought the problem was

void add_part(part_array &data)
{
 data.num++;
 data.array = (part_data*) realloc(data.array, sizeof(part_data)*data.num);
 data.array[data.num - 1] = read_part();
}

Comment: Ok so you really have to return something with `read_part()`. I edit my post so you can see.

Comment: Hey, I noticed that and added "return result;" about 10 mins ago and that didn't resolve it. Maybe we are closer? I appreciate the help...

Is my add_part in my previous comment logical? that's where I am looking at the moment

Comment: @DannyMahoney, please don't post your code in comments. Edit your question instead. It's much more readable that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use pointer instead of references. I would have done something like :

```
    part_data read_part()
    {
        int option;
        part_data result;
        result.name = read_string("Please Enter a name: ");
        result.kind = read_part_kind();
        result.weight = read_float("Please Enter weight: ");
        return result;
    }

    float weight_of_kind(part_array* data, partkind kind)
    {
        int i = 0;
        float result = 0.0;

        for (i = 0; i< data->num; i++);
        {
            if (data->array[i].kind == kind)
            {
                result += data->array[i].weight;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    float total_weight(part_array* data)
    {
        float result = 0.0;
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < data->num; i++)
        {
            result += data->array[i].weight;
        }
        return result;
    }

    void calculate_weight(part_array* data)
    {
        int i;
        printf("Total weight: %4.2f\n", total_weight(data));
        printf("Total CRITICAL: %4.2f\n", weight_of_kind(data, CRITICAL));
        printf("Total DESIRED: %4.2f\n", weight_of_kind(data, DESIRED));
        printf("Total OPTIONAL: %4.2f\n", weight_of_kind(data, OPTIONAL));
    }

partkind read_part_kind()
{
        printf("1 - Critical\n");
        printf("2 - Desired\n");
        printf("3 - Optional\n");
    switch( read_integer_range("Please select a part kind: ", 1, 3) )
    {
        case 1: return CRITICAL;
        case 2: return DESIRED;
        default: return OPTIONAL;
    }
}

part_data read_part()
{
    int option;
    part_data result;

    result.name = read_string("Please Enter a name: ");
    result.kind = read_part_kind();
    result.weight = read_float("Please Enter weight: ");

    return result;
}

void add_part(part_array* data)
{
    data->num++;
    data->array = (part_data*) realloc(data->array, sizeof(part_data)*data->num);
    data->array[data.num - 1] = read_part();
}
```